# How to make the EmailId validator to ignore case in angular 6?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, angular, angular6

I have a register & login page. So for register form I have used the form validator pattern matching.

```
 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
 firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  emailId: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0- 
 9_.+-]+@christmas.com')]],
  //password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required]
 })
```

Im getting the datas from here to nodejs & storing in mysql db. Now for Email Id I need to make it ignorecasesensitivity. How can I do it here. Could anyone please suggest me a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Use the ignore case flag 'i' something like '/your regex/i'.

```
Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@christmas.com/ig)
```

2) Using Angular directive, you can listen for 'input' event and convert your string to lower case email.toLowerCase().

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my day.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern), You can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) object, where you can use the **i** flag to ignore case sensitivity

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  emailId: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[a-z0-9_.+-]+@christmas.com/i)]],
  //password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, But it is not working.. Do I need to inport anything to make this work?